# SQL statement help -- Select customers who ordered today

Tags: sql, datetime, select

Say I have a table which stores customers order IDs. Such as

| Customer ID | Order ID | Order Date

How can I get all customers who have ordered today?

Also OrderDate would be a DateTime.

Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM TableName
Where OrderDate > Today
```

But the last part is what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly common to only want a date out of a datetime - you should be able to Google for the specifics of your RDBMS (since you don't mention it). The important bit is to make your query [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) by transforming *today's* date<sup>1</sup> - not the order date.

For MSSQL, something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM TableName
--I assume you want midnight orders as well - so use >=
Where OrderDate >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

would work by taking number of days today is from Date 0 (`DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())`) and adding them back to Date 0 (`DATEADD(dd, 0, x)`). That's T-SQL specific, though.

<sup>1</sup> If you were searching for an arbitrary date, you'd still transform both arguments:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM TableName
Where 
    OrderDate >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
    --You *do not* want midnight of the next day, as it would duplicate orders
    AND OrderDate < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle the statement would look something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID  
FROM TableName  
Where OrderDate >= trunc(sysdate)
```

SQL-Server should be similar

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `trunc` statement.

Comment: Wow.  I'll have to remember that the next time I interview a candidate.

Every few months I interview someone and hear something like "SQL is SQL".  It doesn't seem to matter that they've been using SQL Server for years and we are an Oracle shop.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM TableName
Where OrderDate = CAST(GetDate() AS NUMERIC)
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM TableName
Where CAST(OrderDate AS NUMERIC) = CAST(GetDate() AS NUMERIC)
```

I have tried to see that it returns the same number for the given date with a different time. So, it should work when a date is converted to its numeric value.

`SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` returns 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM