# Select log lines from today in mysql

Tags: mysql

I never remember how to do this properly - can you help me fix this query?

```
SELECT * from log where now() - EventTime < '1 day'
```

Note - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203826/sql-statement-help-select-customers-who-ordered-today) seems identical but there's no solution there for mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE EventTime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: I know there was another syntax more similar to what I originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE SUBDATE(NOW(), 1) < EventTime
```

Or to only select the ones from today:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE DATE(NOW()) = DATE(EventTime)
```